# creating/changing 3d model file with C++

Tags: c++, 3d, 3d-model

Is there any way to create new (or change existing) .3ds (or any other 3d model type) model using C++?
I've tried to use 3ds max SDK, but it seems to be helpful only to create plug-ins to 3ds max.

Comment: [.3ds Files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.3ds) have a chunk format.  Try finding a .3ds file online (or make one in 3ds max).  Then work on reading that file in and deciphering it's information.  Once you have the info in, you can change it and save it back out no problem. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file is also very common.

Comment: that could be tricky because missing a bit of info is acceptable for model read but for write a new one can cause big inconsistency problems. Better way is use some well documented and simple ASCII exchange format like *.ac3d,*.iges,*.dxf,*.x also 3D Studio has custom ASCII export/import support (where you can see all the data in readable form so it is hard to miss something critical). Problem is only with the support of features you need like material,multi-textures,... so before choosing format look if it supports what you need.

Comment: PS. *.3ds files are not documented by authors instead all the data on the WEB is only decoded and not all chunks are known (or variants of them). so when you write/edit new *.3ds file you can easily end up with something wrong preventing you from open your file with 3ds or some tool. of course if you do not use advanced features than you should be OK with it